# Multiple query using QueryTask ArcgGIS JS Api 3

Tags: javascript, dojo, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I am using QueryTask in ArcgGIS JS Api 3 and I want to execute multiple query in one call, I took a look at the [documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/query-amd.html) and I didn't find the possibility to do it

this is what I am using

```
arraygraphic.map(async (e)=>{
        let query = new esri.tasks.Query();
        query.where = "id = '"+id+"'";
        query.outFields = ["*"];
        let response = await queryTask.execute(query)
      })
```

and this is what I want to do

```
let queryList=[];
arraygraphic.map(async (e)=>{
        let query = new esri.tasks.Query();
        query.where = "id = '"+id+"'";
        query.outFields = ["*"];
        queryList.push(query)
      })
let response = await queryTask.execute(queryList)
```

any suggestion or help ?
thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one "Query", but you can create a better `where` statement that searches for all the "id" in a single `where` statement.

Your where statement would end up looking something like:
`id in (1,2,3,4)`.

You can find more details about the supported SQL under "Request parameters" at https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/enterprise/query-feature-service-layer-.htm#GUID-62EE7495-8688-4BD0-B433-89F7E4476673

Answer (score 1):

If you're not able to put all the queries in one SQL statement as Bjorn suggested (e.g. queries to multiple layers), then you can add the requests to an array and use promise.all to send all the requests
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/query_deferred_list.html